# Display data from Excel in mails

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am using a macro created with help of the Internet community.

It picks up data from Excel and populates Outlook mails. I have `.Display` as I want check content is good and then accept for sending.

I noticed once I send more that 100 records from Excel it creates all new windows with messages in Outlook, but after awhile crashes and closes Outlook.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Mail_Workbook(ToString As String, SubjectString As String, BodyString As String, _
  Optional CCString As String, Optional BCCString As String, Optional AttachmentName As String)
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    On Error Resume Next
   ' Change the mail address and subject in the macro before you run it.
    With OutMail
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "kontakt@xxx.pl"
        .To = ToString
        If CCString <> "" Then
            .CC = CCString
        End If
        If BCCString <> "" Then
            .BCC = BCCString
        End If
        .Subject = SubjectString
        .HTMLBody = BodyString
        If AttachmentName <> "" Then
            .Attachments.Add (AttachmentName)
        End If
        'Choose either Send or Display
        '.Send
        .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim TempFile As String
Dim TempWB As Workbook

TempFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

'Publish the sheet to a htm file
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
    SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
    Filename:=TempFile, _
    Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
    Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
    HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With

'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
RangetoHTML = ts.readall
ts.Close
RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", "align=left x:publishsource=")

'Close TempWB
TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

'Delete the htm file we used in this function
Kill TempFile

Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SendNewMails()

    Dim clE As Range
    Dim shtA As Worksheet

    Set shtA = Sheets("MAKRO")
    Dim SubjectString As String
    SubjectString = Range("Mail_Subject")
   
    For Each clE In Range("Table1[mail]")
        Dim ToString As String
        ToString = clE.Value
        Dim BodyString As String
        BodyString = shtA.Cells(clE.Row, "J")
        Mail_Workbook ToString, SubjectString, BodyString
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: fyi. `On Error Resume Next` just before `With OutMail` is inappropriate 100% of the time. Feel free to remove the `On Error Resume Next` any time you see this structure. Address errors, if any, some other way. Note. Leave it in `Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)`.

Answer (score 3):

The very first thing is to try to figure out which line of code causes the issue. For that you need to remove the `On Error` statements from the code.

Also in the following loop:

```
For Each clE In Range("Table1[mail]")
    Dim ToString As String
    ToString = clE.Value
    Dim BodyString As String
    BodyString = shtA.Cells(clE.Row, "J")
    Mail_Workbook ToString, SubjectString, BodyString
Next
```

a new Outlook Application instance is created and automated:

```
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
```

First, I'd suggest creating a new Outlook `Application` instance once before the loop and re-use it in the method to set up a new item instance.

Second, I'd recommend using the early-binding technology so you could detect issues before running the code. Microsoft recommends early binding in almost all cases. However, there may be reasons for choosing late binding. See [Using early binding and late binding in Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/binding-type-available-to-automation-clients) for more information.

To use the early-binding technology you need:

```
' Set reference to 'Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library' in
' the Project|References dialog (or Tools|References for VB4 or VBA).

' Declare the object as an early-bound object
  Dim outlookApp As Excel.Application

  Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

' Then you may call any property via the v-table
```

A couple of other things that I have noticed in the following piece of code:

```
With OutMail
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = "kontakt@xxx.pl"
        .To = ToString
        If CCString <> "" Then
            .CC = CCString
        End If
        If BCCString <> "" Then
            .BCC = BCCString
        End If
```

1. Make sure that you have sufficient privileges set by the administrator to send on behalf of another person.
2. Use the `Recipients` collection instead of setting text properties for recipients. Then you can resolve recipients against the address book by using the `Resolve`/`ResolveAll` method. See [How To: Fill TO,CC and BCC fields in Outlook programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/08/outlook-fill-recipients-programmatically/) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. Will check your proposals